# How can I run only one ui-test from fastlane?

Tags: xcode, jenkins, xctest, fastlane

how can I run only one ui-test by XCTest from fastlane?

I know about parameters for fastlane: only_testing but not understood how to use this. 
Can you give an example

I run my all ui-tests as:

`fastlane ios RunningUITests`
but want `fastlane ios RunningUITests only_testing:GTUITests/GT00FirstClass/testFunc`
this not work for me

Can you give an  exactly example for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use the `scan` (also known as `run_tests`) "action". Read [this documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/run_tests/#usage) for information.

There, you can see the instructions for calling it directly on the command line. In your example it would be:

```rb
fastlane scan --workspace "<YourRunningUITests>.xcworkspace" --scheme "<YourRunningUITestsScheme>" --only-testing "GTUITests/GT00FirstClass/testFunc"
```

*Replace the values inside of the angled brackets (< >) with the values appropriate to your code.*

However, rather than running that multi-parameter call from the command line, I recommend using a `Fastfile` to consolidate your logic and allow you to perform more sophisticated logic (such as [these `Fastfiles`](https://github.com/fastlane/examples)).

If you were to follow the logic suggested [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/running-tests/), you could then simply call `fastlane tests` from the command line. Much simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot
It's work fine for me
`fastlane scan --project ./Project.xcodeproj --scheme "ProjectUITests" --only_testing "ProjectUITests/GT15InputOneTimeCodeFromEmailUITest"`

Comment: Thanks so much. I have been looking for this for a few hours.

Comment: `fastlane scan --only_test "NameOfUITestDirectory"` worked good for me. Specifying the directory was all I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from above is very useful, the only thing I want to add is that if you want to run more tests, write something like the following:

```
--only-testing "GTUITests/GT00FirstClass/testFunc,GTUITests/GT00FirstClass/testFunc2"
```

You should always write the full path to the test function